# POST Request payload to REST service

Tags: angularjs, rest, post, angular-resource, ngresource

How can I use `$resource` in `ngResource` to make POST requests with request payload to server? I tried passing the object into the `header` property of the action however it did not work.

I am using similar code for this:

```
$resource(myurl, {}, actions).callPOSTAction({}, function() {//remaining logic goes here...});
```

The action "callPOSTAction" is as following...

```
callPOSTAction: {
cache: false,
cancellable: true,
data: {id: 123},
header: {
Content-Type: "application/json",
customToken: {tk:123, pk:456}
},
method: "POST",
timeout: 5000,
url: "https://domain/serviceName"
}
```

After all this, in the Network tab of my developer console, I am not able to see "customToken" being passed to server as a request payload. What am I missing here?

Comment: can you show some code

Comment: Have you tried `<resourceFactoryName>.save(object);`? [Quick reference](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/consuming-external-services/consuming-restful-apis.html)...

Comment: sure we need to see were exactly you getting the error so we help

Comment: Further details added. Please read my question now. Hope it is clear

Comment: Maybe your server does not accept the custom header

Comment: @CodeNashor, Server accepts. But in Google chrome developer console under Network tab I should be able to see this custom header for this POST request. but I'm not able to see. So, is this the right way Im doing?

Comment: Normally, it should be done like : $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: URLl,
                headers: {
                    'My Custom Header': 'test'
                },
                data: myData}).success..... But normally if you send a succesfull request and you dont see the custom header in the request in console, your server does not allow this custom header.

Comment: Is it that $resource does not support this?